# Oracle Datapump API

Tags: oracle, datapump, impdp, expdp

I am rewriting an application, that imports and exports oracle database. I was using imp.exe and exp.exe executed as Processes from code. Now I'm trying to use impdp and expdp instead of them. I studied some samples at https://docs.oracle.com/, however the following code fails at DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE.

```
DECLARE
  h2 NUMBER;
BEGIN    
  h2 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT','SCHEMA',NULL, 'MYJOB', 'LATEST');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h2,'test1.dmp','datapump_dir');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h2,'SCHEMA_EXP','IN (''sc900'')');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h2);
  dbms_datapump.detach(h2);
END;
```

The error output is

```
 ORA-39001: invalid argument value
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3507
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3756
```

I am connected as 'sys' and 'datapump_dir' creation statement was successfully executed.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from creating DATAPUMP_DIR, did you grant READ & WRITE on that directory to user that runs code you wrote?

Comment: yes @Littlefoot

Comment: `SCHEMA_EXP` is [not a valid metadata filter](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_datpmp.htm#BABDDDEF), it's `SCHEMA_EXPR`. I suspect that `sc900` is also invalid and should be upper case, i.e. `q'{IN ('SC900')}'`

Comment: @Ben thanks, i've updated this line, however, as i've written, the problem is in the previous one - "DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h2,'test1.dmp','datapump_dir')"

Comment: Have you rerun the code in addition to changing it? Did you get the exact same error?

Comment: @Ben, yes. fails with the same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will be interested in, I found the problem cause. For some reason, it didn't work, even if I specified default directory. However, when I pass null to this parameter, it works. The following code works, the only disadvantage is that I can save to default directory only

```
DECLARE
  h2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  h2 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT', 'SCHEMA');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h2, 'example0.dmp', null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h2,'SCHEMA_EXPR', q'{IN ('SC900')}');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h2);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.DETACH(h2);
END;
/
```

Comment: Ya. ADD_FILE takes 4 argument.  Typically a directory and a type.  The type can specify the log or dump file.  I would guess null is defaulting the directory and the missing type is defaulting to dump.